# Helm: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch ... with kind Job, by update field image

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy updates. Installation works fine, but when I change the image field in the yaml file for Job and try to roll updates, an error occurs.

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot patch "dev1-test-db-migrate-job" with kind Job: Job.batch "dev1-test-db-migrate-job" is invalid: spec.template: Invalid value: core.PodTemplateSpec{ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string{"controller-uid":"e60854c6-9a57-413c-8f19-175a755c9852", "job-name":"dev1-test-db-migrate-job", "target-app":"db-migrate", "target-domain":"dev1...", "target-service":"test"}, Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:"", ManagedFields:[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry(nil)}, Spec:core.PodSpec{Volumes:[]core.Volume(nil), InitContainers:[]core.Container(nil), Containers:[]core.Container{core.Container{Name:"app", Image:"...:insurance-master-682", Command:[]string{"/bin/sh", "-c"}, Args:[]string{"java -jar ./db/liquibase.jar --logLevel=debug --classpath=./db/mariadb-java-client-2.5.3.jar --driver=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver --changeLogFile=./db/changelog-insurance.xml --url=$DB_HOST --username=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWORD update"}, WorkingDir:"", Ports:[]core.ContainerPort(nil), EnvFrom:[]core.EnvFromSource{core.EnvFromSource{Prefix:"", ConfigMapRef:(*core.ConfigMapEnvSource)(nil), SecretRef:(*core.SecretEnvSource)(0xc01a48c8a0)}}, Env:[]core.EnvVar(nil), Resources:core.ResourceRequirements{Limits:core.ResourceList{"cpu":resource.Quantity{i:resource.int64Amount{value:200, scale:-3}, d:resource.infDecAmount{Dec:(*inf.Dec)(nil)}, s:"200m", Format:"DecimalSI"}, "memory":resource.Quantity{i:resource.int64Amount{value:268435456, scale:0}, d:resource.infDecAmount{Dec:(*inf.Dec)(nil)}, s:"", Format:"BinarySI"}}, Requests:core.ResourceList{"cpu":resource.Quantity{i:resource.int64Amount{value:100, scale:-3}, d:resource.infDecAmount{Dec:(*inf.Dec)(nil)}, s:"100m", Format:"DecimalSI"}, "memory":resource.Quantity{i:resource.int64Amount{value:134217728, scale:0}, d:resource.infDecAmount{Dec:(*inf.Dec)(nil)}, s:"", Format:"BinarySI"}}}, VolumeMounts:[]core.VolumeMount(nil), VolumeDevices:[]core.VolumeDevice(nil), LivenessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), ReadinessProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), StartupProbe:(*core.Probe)(nil), Lifecycle:(*core.Lifecycle)(nil), TerminationMessagePath:"/dev/termination-log", TerminationMessagePolicy:"File", ImagePullPolicy:"IfNotPresent", SecurityContext:(*core.SecurityContext)(nil), Stdin:false, StdinOnce:false, TTY:false}}, EphemeralContainers:[]core.EphemeralContainer(nil), RestartPolicy:"Never", TerminationGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(0xc014591f78), ActiveDeadlineSeconds:(*int64)(nil), DNSPolicy:"ClusterFirst", NodeSelector:map[string]string(nil), ServiceAccountName:"", AutomountServiceAccountToken:(*bool)(nil), NodeName:"", SecurityContext:(*core.PodSecurityContext)(0xc010460000), ImagePullSecrets:[]core.LocalObjectReference{core.LocalObjectReference{Name:"artifactory-tradeplace-registry"}}, Hostname:"", Subdomain:"", Affinity:(*core.Affinity)(nil), SchedulerName:"default-scheduler", Tolerations:[]core.Toleration(nil), HostAliases:[]core.HostAlias(nil), PriorityClassName:"", Priority:(*int32)(nil), PreemptionPolicy:(*core.PreemptionPolicy)(nil), DNSConfig:(*core.PodDNSConfig)(nil), ReadinessGates:[]core.PodReadinessGate(nil), RuntimeClassName:(*string)(nil), Overhead:core.ResourceList(nil), EnableServiceLinks:(*bool)(nil), TopologySpreadConstraints:[]core.TopologySpreadConstraint(nil)}}: field is immutable

I still didn’t understand which field should be immutable, probably Image, but it’s very strange, it makes sense that I can embed Image.

The error occurs when I change the field Image from ...: insurance-master-682 to ...: insurance-master-681 for example

I change the chart file every time I install or update, I change the version field.
So, has anyone encountered this?
while I see the only way out is to apply 'kubectl delete job ...' before updating

part of yamls in 'templetes' directory:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  labels:
    target-domain: dev1...
    target-service: test
  name: dev1-test-db-migrate-job
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        target-app: db-migrate
        target-domain: dev1...
        target-service: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
            - java -jar ./db/liquibase.jar --logLevel=debug --classpath=./db/mariadb-java-client-2.5.3.jar
              --driver=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver --changeLogFile=./db/changelog-insurance.xml
              --url=$DB_HOST --username=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWORD update
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: dev1-secret-config-deploy-for-app-gk5b59mb86
          image: ...:insurance-master-682
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: app
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 200m
              memory: 256Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: artifactory-tradeplace-registry
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Chart.yaml example

```
apiVersion: v2
name: 
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
type: application
version: 0.1.20200505t154055
appVersion: 1.16.0
```

Comment: That is correct. You can't change the image of a `Job`.

Comment: @suren oh, it's sad, but thanks

Comment: I noticed the same error, when I changed an Image and some Env variables in the values.yaml. Somehow helm upgrade --install fails to apply the changes and just requires a fresh install.

Answer (score 13):

The existing job need to be deleted, because the template section in the job is immutable or not updatable. so you have 2 following options.

1. Always create a new job with a unique name, so it leaves the old jobs and creates a new one - every time if you include the version of image would be sensible.
2. Automatic cleaning of jobs (more info [check here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#clean-up-finished-jobs-automatically)) - The job property `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` allows helps to delete the job automatically after a sepecified period.
   for eg:

```
    apiVersion: batch/v1
    kind: Job
    metadata:
      name: pi-with-ttl
    spec:
      ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: pi
            image: perl
            command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to delete the existing job and rerun. may not be able to rerun the same job. the problem seems to be the job name. I do see similar when I try to upgrade with the same name, ex:  "dev1-test-db-migrate-job".